# GetStream - Flutter - Connection already available for user

Tags: flutter, dart, getstream-io

Error facing in Flutter GetStream SDK..
GetStream is chatting SDK in which I am using `messaging feature`.
I am facing issue with creating connection with the user.

**Even if I change name of the user to anything,
I still get the same error.**

[image]

While the Log shows the following result.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stream Chat only supports one user connection at a time. You'll see it says "Connection already available..."

You first need to disconnect the current user, with:

```dart
await cle.disconnectUser();
```

Before calling `connectUser` again.